# Open pull request by number in Visual Studio Code without cloning it

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, pull-request

Is there a way to open a github pull request in VS Code by its number *without checking out the remote branch*? Or is this not possible because VS Code would not be able to show the correct version (corresponding commit) of the code in the PR?

There is the option "Checkout pull request by number", but this may not always be what I want and will not work if the remote branch has been deleted after the pull request was merged.